# How to do Norton equivalent circuit? Why part of the circuit can be ignored?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I read the solution. It said that the 10mA and 10Kohm is not going to affect the circuit, so that it can be ignored. However, I don't understand why. Please help.

If I really want to include those 10mA and 10Kohm, how I can approach this question?

[image]

Comment: Redraw the circuit by replacing the circuit to the left of 30V source with its Thevnin's equivalent circuit and try again.

Answer (score 1):

If you're finding the Norton equivalent looking into the "a" and "b" terminals, the 30V ideal voltage source keeps the voltage at its positive node at a constant 30V, regardless of anything in parallel with it.  So any components to the left of the ideal source can't affect the output across the a-b terminals.  You can write the mesh equations or simplify the circuit in any way you like, but you will come up with the same result regardless.

Remember, an IDEAL source has zero source impedance and regardless of what you put across it will force the voltage to its given value.

Comment: I have still have a question of the 10mA current source. If I use a node voltage approach to find the current across the 15kohm, there will have different if the 10mA source is present or not, isn't it? However, why I can ignore the current source during Norton equivalent?

Comment: No, the voltage at the top of the 15K resistor is (by definition of an ideal source) 30V and the current through the resistor is ALWAYS 2mA.  You could put a 100A source in place of the 10mA source and the answer would be the same.  And we talk about the current THROUGH and the voltage ACROSS, not the current across.

Comment: The excess current (the 10mA from the current source minus the 2mA in the 15K resistor) flows through the 30V source.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the 30V voltage source is an ideal (perfect) source, it has zero output impedance.  That is: you can take as much current from it or push as much current into it as you wish and the output voltage of 30V will not change.

The two items to the left of the voltage source are in parallel with it and can therefore be ignored.

You are asking how you can include the 10 mA current source and the 10k resistor in your solution.  You can't.  There are literally invisible to the (a) & (b) terminals.

Comment: I have still have a question of the 10mA current source. If I use a node voltage approach to find the current across the 15kohm, there will have different if the 10mA source is present or not, isn't it? However, why I can ignore the current source during Norton equivalent?